# Array keys ,get array values ,then comma separate

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have :

```
$a = array(
    0=>'you',
    1=>'will',
    2=>'be',
    3=>'so',
    4=>'happy',
    5=>'in'
);

$b = array(
    0=>'1',
    1=>'4',
    2=>'5'
);   // (KEYS:1,4,5)
```

I want out the values of $a that matches $b's keys;

so $val would be `willhappyin`.

And then comma-separate them.. like: `will,happy,in` without comma after last one.

How can i do this ? :)

Comment: What i have tried is somewhat like this, but i thought i had it all wrong.. and i was right :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$string = implode(",", array_intersect_key($a, array_flip($b)));
```

**EXPLANATION:**

[array_flip](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) switches the **values** of $b to **keys**.

[array_intersect_key](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) takes only the entries in $a that are also present in $b.

[implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) joins the resulting array values together by comma.

Comment: wow , first time hearing about this function `array_intersect_keys` - will use it in the future!

Comment: It's actually `array_intersect_key`.

Comment: @OfirBaruch: Actually, the function is `array_intersect_key` (no s on the end). See corrected answer.

Comment: Wow.. so easy :) here i have played with foreach for hours without getting my results.

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 2):

```
$c = array();
foreach($b as $key)
{
  $c[] = $a[$key]
}

echo implode(",",$c);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$out_arr = array();
foreach ($b as $k => $v) {
  array_push($out_arr, $a[$v]);
}

return join($out_arr, ',');
```